# do you know this? about android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

My source code is as follows:

in MainActivity:

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case LOGIN_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle bd = new Bundle();
            bd = data.getBundleExtra("bundle");
        }
    }
    default:
    {
        Log.d(DEBUG_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME, "ERROR : onActivityResult - unknown activity code");
    }
    }
}
```

And second activity's code is:

```
public void returnToGameActivity(Bundle bundle) {                                       
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
        this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
    }
```

But i can't receive data 'bd' of Bundle type in onActivityResult() in MainActivity. Why?

But in this case, i can get data of bd:

in second activity,

```
putExtra("string", "test string");
```

and in MainActivity,

```
String str = getStringExtra("string");
```

Why i can't get data in bundle type?

Comment: *but in this case, i can get data of bd.*, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

To transfer a Bundle element from one activity to other,use the following code:

```
Intent i=new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
        //i.putExtra("mylist",amt);
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
         b.putSerializable("bundleinterest", (Serializable) amtint);
         b.putSerializable("bundleobj", (Serializable) amt);
            i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
```

In Second.class:

```
        Bundle bn = new Bundle();
         bn = getIntent().getExtras();
         getobj = new ArrayList<CompoundAmount>();
         getinterestobj=new ArrayList<CompoundIntAmount>();
         getobj = (ArrayList<CompoundAmount>) bn.getSerializable("bundleobj");
         getinterestobj = (ArrayList<CompoundIntAmount>) bn.getSerializable("bundleinterest");
```

Explanation:

**Use Serializable or Parcelable** interfaces while transferring Bundles.
Your set-get class must implements Serializable as:

```
public class CompoundIntAmount implements Serializable {

     private final String amt;



     public CompoundIntAmount(String amt){
         this.amt = amt;

     }

     public String getIntAmount() {
         return amt;
     }

}
```

Here CompoundAmount and CompoundIntAmount are custom set-get classes which must implement Serializable(like the one above).